# OCaml, how do i run a textfile with code in windows?

Tags: ocaml

This is probably a really simple question, but i can't get it working.
I have installed the cygwin for windows. I have a textfile with some code in it:

```
# let rec last_two = function
  | [] -> None
  | [x] -> None
  | [x;y] -> (x,y)
  | x::y -> last_two y;;

# print_endline last_two [1;2;3;4]
```

how do i execute this textfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command is simple:

```
ocaml filename.ml
```

But, as it was [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26757608/2625442) by cago, your code won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return an 'a option in every case:

```
let rec last_two = function
  | [] | [_] -> None
  | [x; y] -> Some (x, y)
  | hd :: tl -> last_two tl;;
```